# Keyboard does not appear after usage of <select>, in Wikitude ArWorld

Tags: html, cordova, input, keyboard, wikitude

I'm developing an android Augmented Reality app using wikitude Phonegap Plugin, and in some action, I need the user to complete a .
In this form, there are s and a . Inputs works nicely, however, after the use of the select, clicking in an input wont show keyboard after all.
I guess the problem is with Wikitude Ar, 'cause when I access the form html by its own, everything is OK. The bug happens when I access it inside the ArWorld or after using the ArWorld, even when I close it with wikitudePlugin.close().

Sorry for bad English, not main language. Hope someone have already experienced it.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is what I've tried:
      1 - Inserting the form inside a Jquery Panel
      2 - using Jquery Load() to load a .html containing the form in a Jquery Panel
      3 - closing the World with WikitudePlugin.close() and calling the form .html with window.open() and window.location.href = ;
     Nothing Works.

When I call the form .html before opening a Ar World, it works

Comment: please can you show me your code .

Comment: Did it. Sorry for the long wait.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML form is:

```
<body>        
    <h1>Cadastro de Fissura</h1>
    <form action="">
        <label for="fissuraObservacao">Observação</label>
        <textarea name="fissuraObservacao" id="fissuraObservacao" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>        
        <label for="fissuraFaceBloco">Face do Bloco</label>
        <input type="text">    
         <select autofocus name="fissuraAlarme" id="fissuraAlarme">
                <option value="1">Normal</option>
                <option value="2">Alerta</option>
                <option value="3">Urgente</option>
          </select>    
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        <input type="reset" value="Limpar">
    </form>                                
</body>
```

In javaScript, a button call a funcion  with

```
document.location = 'architectsdk://action=openCadastroHtml';
```

which is used in

```
onURLInvoked: function onURLInvoke(url){
        if (url.substring(22) == 'openCadastroHtml'){
            app.wikitudePlugin.close();
            //window.location.href = 'world/inspecao/cadastro.html';
            window.open('world/inspecao/cadastro.html','_');
            .
            . 
            .
```

where cadastro.html is the HTML form

Comment: Nope, everything was fine